# open source, multi-platform, browser-based screen capture extension?

Tags: open-source, cross-browser, screen-capture, browser-extension

I'm considering a project that involves the browser user being able to screen capture the contents of any web page (preferably the whole page, not just the visible portion), do some simple annotation on the image (circles, arrows, underlines, text labels) and send the annotated image to the server.

I see that there are several commercial or freeware browser-based screen capture utilities (which I can't use for this project because it requires specific communications with a specific server).

I'm considering writing my own set of extensions, but it's a little daunting, partly because of the COM complexities for IE, but more generally because it seems like such extensions would break easily with browser updates, and since I want it to work across multiple browsers it seems like it could quickly become a maintenance nightmare.

Do you know of any open source browser-based screen capture extensions? Nice would be code examples showing how to do this on various browsers. Great would be an actively supported library.

Comment: Not really open source, but here's another option which does offer a free plan: [bugsnag.com](//bugsnag.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M Katz,

That's a tough one, personally I'd use BugDigger to capture and annotate pages in a browser. That said, I'm not sure if it is cross-browser compatible to a broad enough degree for you.

One idea though, is to install it then scan it's program folder to see if you see a 3rd party library they may utilize for the capture. If you don't see one, it could be they wrote their own.

http://bugdigger.com/

Good luck!